# statically linked nearest function won't evaluate properly in C

Tags: c, unix, aix

Compiler used is CC of AIX. Below code shows the before and after difference.

```
$cat tst1.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  int val1=nearest((double)(1.5)),val2=nearest((double)(2.5)),val3=nearest((double)(2.6));
  /*Before*/
  printf("nearest 1.5 ==> %d\n",val1);
  printf("nearest 2.5 ==> %d\n",val2);
  printf("nearest 2.6 ==> %d\n",val3);
  /*After*/
  printf("nearest 1.5 ==> %d\n",nearest((double)(1.5)));
  printf("nearest 2.5 ==> %d\n",nearest((double)(2.5)));
  printf("nearest 2.6 ==> %d\n",nearest((double)(2.6)));
  return 0;
}

$cc -c tst1.c
$cc tst1.o -o tst1 -lm
$./tst1
nearest 1.5 ==> 2
nearest 2.5 ==> 2
nearest 2.6 ==> 3
nearest 1.5 ==> 1073741824
nearest 2.5 ==> 1073741824
nearest 2.6 ==> 1074266112
```

Question is why does return value of nearest() have to be assigned to a variable to be printed correctly? I guess this concerns the static linking used, but couldn't figure out why.

Comment: Post code of nearest()

Comment: @HAL http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.basetechref%2Fdoc%2Fbasetrf1%2Ffloor.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `nearest` does not return an `int`. When you assign it to an `int`, C does the conversion, so printing it with the `%d` format is successful. When you call it, C leaves the value as is. That's why printing with `%d` fails the second time.

Adding an explicit cast will fix this problem:

```
/*After*/
printf("nearest 1.5 ==> %d\n",(int)nearest(1.5));
printf("nearest 2.5 ==> %d\n",(int)nearest(2.5));
printf("nearest 2.6 ==> %d\n",(int)nearest(2.6));
```

Comment: Did I mention this is another one of the many 'Duh!' moments for me? ;-p

Answer (score 2):

Most probably `nearest` returns something else than `int`, so the format specification is incorrect the second time. Conversions between numeric types are implicit, so the assignment just works.

By the way, `(double)1.5` is a superfluous cast, because literals containing decimal point default to `double`.